# Adding a variable time field (24 format) and a variable datetime field (m/d/yy h:MM tt) to produce result in another field

Tags: javascript, datetime

Please help!  I am a very novice JavaScript user and have scoured the forums trying to find an answer to my problem:

I have two fields that are variable I am trying to add them together in a separate field.
One field (TotHr) is in `HH:MM` format, and the other is a datetime field (DTin1) that is in `m/d/yy h:MM tt` format.
I need the output to read in the same format as the datetime field.
This will be utilized on various consoles throughout my work, so I would like to not use a library like moment.js.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var date = new Date();
var dateMil = date.getTime("DTin1");
var timePeriod = ("TotHr");

var parts = timePeriod.split(/:/);
var timePeriodMil = (parseInt(parts[0], 10) * 60 * 60 * 1000) +
                (parseInt(parts[1], 10) * 60 * 1000) + 
                (parseInt(parts[2], 10) * 1000);

var newDate = new Date();
newDate.setTime(dateMil + timePeriodMil);

console.log(newDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it in JavaScript. A simple way is to use some library e.g. the following code uses [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library.

```
const { duration } = require('moment')
const moment = require('moment-timezone')

let strDuration = "10:30"
let strDateTime = "9/6/21 5:10 am"
let format = 'M/D/YY h:m a'

dur = moment.duration(strDuration)
dt = new moment(strDateTime, format)

result = dt.add(dur).tz('Europe/London').format(format)

console.log(result)
```

**Output:**

```
9/6/21 3:40 pm
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  Would you be able to direct me how to do this in just JS, not using moment.js?  Thanks again!